# Subquery not returning data when combining two different datasets

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g, google-bigquery

I am trying to combine two different datasets with a subquery on Google BigQuery.

When I use the subquery by itself, it runs and it returns for every year the total average temperature. However, when I incorporate the query as a subquery, it only returns the average temperature for all the period stated and not for every year.

My code:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT t1.year, gas_fuel, liquid_fuel, solid_fuel, cement, annual_anomaly, (SELECT avg(temp)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod*`
WHERE year > '1982') as average_temperature
FROM `cs779-term-project.CO2_FossilFuel.GlobalEmissions` as t1
JOIN `cs779-term-project.CO2_FossilFuel.SeaLevels` as t2
on t1.year = t2.year
Where t1.year > 1982
ORDER BY t1.year ASC;
```

Also, when I add a `GROUP BY year` in the subquery, it shows me the following error:

> Error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to show the `avg(tmp)` for `t1.year` as `average_temperature`? Then you might want to change the predicate `year > '1982'`in the subquery to `year = t1.year`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks! The problem with this is that year > '1982' is a string while year = t1.year it's an integer. So it now says: Error: No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRING, INT64. Supported signatures: ANY = ANY at [5:9]. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need average temperature in year, then you need use year from query in subquery condition:

```
SELECT t1.year, gas_fuel, liquid_fuel, solid_fuel, cement, annual_anomaly
, (SELECT avg(temp)
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod*`
  WHERE year = t1.year) as average_temperature
FROM `cs779-term-project.CO2_FossilFuel.GlobalEmissions` as t1
JOIN `cs779-term-project.CO2_FossilFuel.SeaLevels` as t2
on t1.year = t2.year
Where t1.year > 1982
ORDER BY t1.year ASC;
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks! The problem with this is that year > '1982' is a string while year = t1.year it's an integer. So it now says: Error: No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRING, INT64. Supported signatures: ANY = ANY at [5:9]. Any ideas?

Comment: cast/convert/concatenate? for example concatenate in oracle `year  =  '' || t1.year`

Comment: Yes! I used the cast function instead because the concatenate did not work. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code that I used and run:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT t1.year, gas_fuel, liquid_fuel, solid_fuel, cement, annual_anomaly
, (SELECT avg(temp)
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod*`
  WHERE CAST(year as INT64) = t1.year) as average_temperature
FROM `cs779-term-project.CO2_FossilFuel.GlobalEmissions` as t1
JOIN `cs779-term-project.CO2_FossilFuel.SeaLevels` as t2
on t1.year = t2.year
Where t1.year > 1982
ORDER BY t1.year ASC;
```